# Cordova for Iphone InAppBrowser - How to disable URL and also Navigation Bar and Done button

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

```
iabRef = window.open('http://', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
```

Comment: my code is above line but its not working for me ...!!
if location hide then nave tool bar done button show and button hide then location show.
 i want to hide both button and url location and navigation bar ..!!

Comment: might be a bug, I'll take a look

Comment: BTW, don't repeat the questions, you already opened this [Cordova for Iphone InAppBrowser - How to disable URL and also Navigation Bar Done button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974553/cordova-for-iphone-inappbrowser-how-to-disable-url-and-also-navigation-bar-don)